# How to pass caller function name to callee function using default parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Consider the below code :

```
#include <iostream>

void test_function(const char* caller_name = __FUNCTION__) {
  std::cout << caller_name << " ";
}

void func1() {
  test_function();
}

int main() {
  test_function();
  func1();
}
```

The above code prints nothing.
Is there any way that test_function prints the name of the function from which it is called ?

Eg : For this case, output should be : main func1

I understand that desired output can be achieved if we make the argument to test_function, non default, and pass __FUNCTION__ from the caller function.

 This could be achieved by using macro also, but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Why did you tag those particular language versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a macro

```
#define TEST_FUNCTION() test_function(__FUNCTION__)

void test_function(const char *caller) {
  std::cout << caller << '\n';
}

void foo() {
  TEST_FUNCTION(); // prints foo
}

int main() {
  TEST_FUNCTION(); // prints main
  foo();
}
```

Comment: Yes this is a way. But if we have multiple functions like test_function, then we have to define macro for each one of them. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why do you have multiple functions that take the name of the caller? Is this for logging?

Comment: Yes, it is for logging.

Comment: @kapil There is no other way. You can either use a macro or write `test_function(__FUNCTION__)`

Comment: You can deal with defining many macros with... another macro! https://pastebin.com/0jvdiiAZ

Comment: @saffronsnail Of course, but then the call site is pretty ugly

Comment: And there shouldn't be *that many* functions. It's just a logging system.

Comment: @kerndog73 The calling site should be the same as with no extra macro, it's the function definition that gets wrecked. There's needs to be at tradeoff somewhere though, either by making the definition less pretty or typing the boilerplate macro definition.